# Regex: extract String from String

Tags: java, regex

I need a regex that makes it possible to extract a part out of String. I get this String by parsing a XML-Document with DOM. Then I am looking for the "§regex" part in this String and now I try do extract the value of it. e.g. "([A-ZÄÖÜ]{1,3}[- ][A-Z]{1,2}[1-9][0-9]{0,3})" from the rest.

The Problem is, I don´t know how to make sure the extracted part ends with a ")"
This regex needs to work for every value given. The goal is to write only the Value in brackets after the "§regex=" including the brackets into a String.

```
<UML:TaggedValue tag="description" value=" random Text §regex=([A-ZÄÖÜ]{1,3}[- ][A-Z]{1,2}[1-9][0-9]{0,3}) random text"/>

private List<String> findRegex() {
    List<String> forReturn = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (String str : attDescription) {
        if (str.contains("§regex=")) {
            String s = str.replaceAll(regex);
            forReturn.add(s);
        }
    }
    return forReturn;
}
```

attDescription is a list which contains all Attributes found in the XML-Document parsed.

So far i tried this regex: `".*(§regex=)(.*)[)$].*", "$2"` but this cuts off the ")" and does not delete the text infront of the searched part. Even with the help of this  http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html I really don´t understand how to get what I need.

Comment: You should provide some examples of the strings to match and the expected result, without this strange §regex decoration. The code snippet is confusing - what is regex?

Comment: It's pretty limiting to assume that the regex will have no capturing groups, non-capturing groups, literal parens, or spaces. So it seems like, unless you can know the structure of the text that follows it, I don't see how you can do it. Perhaps the regex can also *end* with `=regex[squiggle]`. Then you would have a clear delimiter to search for. Do you have control over the input in this way? (I'd also consider using a more standard character other than the squiggle thing.)

Comment: replaceAll needs a second parameter.

Comment: Try this: `".*§regex=(\\(.*\\)).*", "$1"`

Comment: Also, the dollar sign in your regex, `.*(§regex=)(.*)[)$].*`, can't work, as it's expecting text to exist after the end of the line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to work for me (with this example anyway) if I use this in place of `String s = str.replaceAll(regex);`

```
String s = str.replaceAll( ".*§regex=(\\(.*\\)).*", "$1" );
```

It's just looking for a substring enclosed by parentheses following `§regex=`.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work:

```
String s = str.replaceAll(".*§regex=\\((.*)[)].*", "$1");
```

Note:

- Escape the leading bracket
- The $ inside a character class is a literal $ - ignore it, because your regex should always end with a bracket
- No need to capture the fixed text

---

Test code, noting that this works with brackets in/around the regex:

```
String str = "random Text §regex=(([A-ZÄÖÜ]{1,3}[- ][A-Z]{1,2}[1-9][0-9]{0,3})) random text";
String s = str.replaceAll(".*§regex=\\((.*)[)].*", "$1");
System.out.println(s);
```

Output:

```
([A-ZÄÖÜ]{1,3}[- ][A-Z]{1,2}[1-9][0-9]{0,3})
```